# TYPO3 personalization : xclass system VS diff/patch approach

Tags: diff, patch, typo3

What is the most convenient method to personalize the behavior of TYPO3 project and modules if there is no hooks available ?

TYPO3 xclass system of traditional diff / patch approach, based on Subversion or git ?

Answer (score 0):

If you think that there is a general interest in having such a hook, you could push a request to Gerrit (see http://wiki.typo3.org/Contribution_Walkthrough_Tutorials).

XCLASSing works well but the problem is that you might have to adjust the XCLASSes for each major version.

Comment: My question is actually about maintaing modifications. I have too much personalization to ask about hundreds of hooks in Core and 3rd party extensions, so the question is about what is better to maintain : xclass or direct patching.

Comment: I would go for the XCLASS approach because by using XCLASS you're using a TYPO3 core concept. You don't need to patch sources for all minor updates which happen to be released quite often. (For me, the question remains why you need so heavy patching.)

Comment: Ok. Heavy patching required by client's requests to personalize TYPO3 behavior.

Comment: Maybe you should think about which of those modifications can be of value to the TYPO3 community and try to give some of them back. And maybe you should think about whether you missed some configuration options, because TYPO3 is quite flexible, but that is hard to judge without knowing your modifications ;)

Answer (score 0):

XCLASS was invented for such an use case. So i would prefer an xclass instead of an diff. If you write an XClass, it can be stable over many versions. Especially if you need to change only a few short methods.

On the first glance a diff looks quicker and easier, but i guess it is not.

But if if is possible, you should consider to use a Hook instead. Especially if you want to XCLASS an extension, contact the author first.